# Algorithm for overlapping sets

Tags: java, algorithm

There is a game consists of N rounds. After each round, the winner (either you or me) will be awarded one point. The player with more points at the end of the game wins.

You wants that after each round in the game you are having at least M times the points than me.

```
For Example N=3 , M=1
the possible sequence of winners of rounds are:
DDD     // D is you and M is me
DMD
DDM

MDD    // Is not possible as you are having 1 point and i am having zero so condition violted
```

**My approach:**

In a particular game the only two possibilities are that you win or I win, so I make a recursive call to calculate the score for both the possibilities.

```
                                   D           
                                M           D          // At M+1 game(M wins or D wins)
                              D or M      D or M       // At M+2 game(M wins or D wins)
                    .
                    .
                    . ans so on
                                 At last round return 1
```

**Code:**

```
public static int score(int rounds, int m, int score1, int current, int score2) {
    int sum=0;

    if (current == rounds && score2 == 0) return 1;
    if (current == rounds && score1 / score2 >= m) return 1;
    if (score2 != 0 && score1 / score2 < m) return 0;
    if (score2 == 0 || score1 / score2 >= m) {
        sum += score(rounds, m, score1, current + 1, score2 + 1);
        sum += score(rounds, m, score1 + 1, current + 1, score2);
    }
    return sum;
}

System.out.println(score(rounds,m,m,m,0));
```

This solution is taking very long time for larger value of N in the range of 10^6. How can i speed up my approach.

Comment: Well yes, if there are 10^6 rounds then there are 2^(10^6) possible outcomes. That's a very, very large number...

Comment: @JonSkeet would you help how to tackle this...problem

Comment: I would need to think carefully about that, but it's not a matter of speeding up your approach - it's a matter of *changing* approach. Anything which executes even a single line of code for every possibility is going to fail.

Comment: What exactly is your algorithm trying to compute?  The number of sequences where I win M times more than you?  Is it trying to generate the Win/Loss sequences where I win M times more?  This isn't clear to me.

Comment: @TravisJ i want numbers of ways only

Comment: In that case you don't need any computation at all really.  I will put a complete answer below.

Comment: @JonSkeet could you just give me a direction how to proceeded as i have to calculate the numbers of ways only!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are going to play N games (in sequence) and at each step you record whether player A wins or player B wins.  You generate a sequence that looks like AABABBAABA, etc.  You want to count the number of such sequences where there are M times as many A's as B's (I assume you mean at least M times as many).  Since N is fixed, you have an upper bound on the number of B's.  I.e. #B's + #A's = N and #A's >= M*#B's, so (M+1)*#B's <= N and so #B's <= N/(M+1).

Let us say, that you can have at most K B's in the string (and there are N characters total).  For each 1 <= k <= K there are N choose k ways to place the B's (assuming you have k of them) and the rest are A's.  In total, then, there are SUM(k=0..K) (N choose k) such possibilities.

So instead of using the code to generate all these, just have your code compute the (N choose k) values and sum them up.